# serialization using generics

Tags: java, object, serializable

Below is a piece of code for serializing objects , but using generics.
There was no .ser file created when i executed this method. I am sure I mite be missing on some important concept of generics here. Please help me out !

```
public <T> void saveToDisk(List<T> objectlist) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println(path);
    if ("domain_pojo.Customer".equals(objectlist.getClass().getName()))
        file = "/customer.ser";
    else if ("domain_pojo.Employees"
            .equals(objectlist.getClass().getName()))
        file = "/employee.ser";
    else if ("domain_pojo.Orders".equals(objectlist.getClass().getName()))
        file = "/order.ser";

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path + file);
        // Create ObjectOutputStream to write object
        ObjectOutputStream objOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        // Write object to file
        System.out.println("Size of objectlist is :" + objectlist.size());
        // objectlist.add(null);
        for (T obj : objectlist) {
            objOutputStream.writeObject(obj);
            objOutputStream.reset();
        }
        objOutputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        new FileParsingException(e, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is "file" declared, and what value does it have it if fails all three of the conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if ("domain_pojo.Customer".equals(objectlist.getClass().getName()))

This line is always false (and the case is same with other else IF blocks as well) as the value of `objectlist.getClass()` will always be java.util.List.

You should instead pass `Class<T> clazz` and use that in the comparison.

On a related note, it would be better to have the class implement some interface method that returns the file name, instead of hard-coding like this.

Comment: +1, but might be better if you mentioned 'Type Erasure' out loud ;)